# How to connect two Ubuntu Laptops without any LAN or C-Type Cable?

Tags: networking, lenovo, hp

I have two laptops first one is `HP G7-notebook` and 2nd one is `Lenovo ideapad`. Both laptops are installed with Ubuntu 22.4

In my HP laptop, there is no LAN option. Only have USB and C Type. I am trying to connect it through WiFi.

While I share any folder from HP laptop. That folder shows in my Lenovo laptop as the 1st laptop's name. But when I clicked on that I got an error message. Please check the below image and let me know how can I connect that.
[image]

*If anybody know how we connect it through WiFi please answer here.*

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your information. I am upgrading my OS once done then will inform you. Hence I am deleting this question

Comment: @guiverc I Am still facing the same issue after upgrading my Ubuntu version from 21.4 to 22.4. Please help me

Comment: What do you intend to achieve by connecting laptop HP to laptop Lenovo? Please edit your question so your goal is clear.
Except this: based on HP's data sheet for the G7 series , your laptop has a USB 3.1 type C Thunderbolt port, hence it supports LAN. You just need a USB C -> LAN adapter or a USB C dock featuring a LAN port.

Comment: @noisefloor my issue has been fixed. Posted answer. please check

Comment: @Chinmay235 If you delete this question you will lose the reputation points that you have earned for your answer. Please leave as is.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: Did you directly connect the two laptops by LAN / USB cables,  or cables to a router, or via WiFi?

Comment: @user68186 initially I was connecting it through the USB Cable. But I did not get any solution. After some R&D I can able to connect via WiFi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was solved by running the below command

```
sudo smbpasswd -a chinmay
```

It was showing an error message because I have not set the SMB password. After the password is set, Now it's connected.

`chinmay` is my PC username - you can use your own. No need to connect any C-Type or LAN cable. You need to stay in the same network.

Comment: Based on the rather limited information in your answer, I'm assuming the answer to your original question is "Don't use a C type cable to do this" and that you are connecting the 2 machines over WiFi. You might clarify this by rewriting your question and/or your answer.